# The axis-x labels show the half with XTickLabel

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using XTicklabel to change the numbers to labe. I've got 18 numbers, and 18 coresponding labels. But, it takes only half of the labels (just up to half). The codes are:

```
ab=[230, 231,233, 238, 239, 241, 253, 257, 269, 270, 272, 276, 277, 279, 297, 300, 311,315];
rr=[];
for i=1:length(ab)
rr=[rr,length(find(N(ab(i), :)>0.5))/72];
end
x=1:length(ab);
plot(x, rr)
set(gca,'XLim',[1 length(ab)])
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',{'oo' ,'ho', 'go', 'oh','hh' ,'gh' ,'fg', 'gg' ,'oe', 'he','ge', 'of' ,'hf', 'gf' ,'fc', 'gc' ,'fr', 'gr'})
```

N is a  matrix of 322 X 72.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to set the `XTickLabels`, you need to change to `XTick`-value also!

Try: `set(gca,'XTick',1:18);`.